# How to split and count the words with single quotes (')?

Tags: php, regex

I want to split word like **who's** and count it into 2 words:

who = 1

s = 1

I think it will use preg_split to do this job, but I don't understand how to do it.

Comment: Why not [explode](http://php.net/EXPLODE)? `$str = explode($other_string, "'");`

Comment: ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

Comment: You really need to show us your actual code and what the string is. This is anybody's *guess*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use explode() to get it.

```
$word= "who's'who";
$results= array();
$parts = explode ("'", $word);
foreach ($parts as $part) $results[$part]++;
```

You then may output like:

```
foreach ($results as $word => $count) echo $word . " = " . $count. "<br>";
```

The output should be:

> who = 2
>
> s = 1

Comment: What's `foreach ($parts as $part) $array[$part]++;` for?

Comment: I add 1 to the value of $array["who"] so it counts up. If there is the second one, it will count to 2.

Comment: adjusted variable names for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use preg_split:

```
$str = "who's";
$words = preg_split("/\'/", $str);
```

But, as others have mentioned, `explode` is far easier, and will have better performance